# How to load IFRAMES which was used on site on Webview xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, webview, xcode10

I have a site, in which several iframe is loading. I Test the site and it is fully functionaled.

Now For IOS Webview, I implemented the code.

My site is completely transformed into IOS App. But the problem is that I frames is not loading. I test this On browser and it works fine. All IFrames are loading properly, but not on IOS Webview APP.

My ViewController.swift Code is:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
   var webView: WKWebView!

   override func loadView() {
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
       webView.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate
       webView.navigationDelegate = self
       view = webView
   }
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.4:8080")!
       webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
       webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
   }


}
```

Can anyone suggest me why it is not loading.

Any help or suggestion is really apreciated